# Sockets Winsock async blocking Read Write simultaneously

Tags: multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, io, winsock

I have a client server arch and I am using blocking win sockets. I have a read and a write thread both on the server and on the client side.

Say Client is waiting (blocked) on a read() call for server to write stuff to,

can The client write something to that socket while it is blocked on a read() call from another thread.
So does block affect full duplex bidirectonal sockets ? I understand that I will block on the read but why would it also block on the write()?

or in order for this to work do I have to use select() or poll()?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can The client write something to that socket while it is blocked on a read() call from another thread

Yes, this is no problem at all.